# Independent Exponential Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, exponential-function

I am currently trying to figure out a problem and it is using notation that I have never seen before so I am pretty stuck, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Let $X, Y, Z$ be independent exponential random variables with the same mean, $σ$. Find the value of $σ$ so that $\Pr[\max(X,Y,Z)>1]=0.05$.

Any help with how to solve this problem or leading down the right path would be awesome as I am not to sure where to even start!

EDIT: So I have followed what André Nicolas has said and got a $σ$ of $0.25$. However I am still not sure where he got this formula from: The probability they are all $\le a$ is $(1-e^{-a/\sigma})^3$.

I cant find anything like this is my notes or textbook, could any reference where he got this?

Comment: Suggested reading: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17164/suggested-guideline-for-i-dont-know-where-to-begin-questions

Comment: One probability trick very often useful is converting the problem to a complementary probability:  $Pr[\max(X,Y,Z) \gt 1] = 1 - Pr[\max(X,Y,Z) \le 1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A start:** The probability that $\max(X,Y,Z)\gt 1$ is $1$ minus the probability they are all $\le 1$.

The probability they are all $\le a$ is $(1-e^{-a/\sigma})^3$.

Comment: So basically the max is used instead of putting >=?

Comment: I am using the fact that for any random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$, we have $\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)\gt t$ precisely if he $X_i$ are not all $\le t$. Once we have translated the max stuff to more familiar language, we can attack the problem using the usual tools. We want $(1-e^{-1/\sigma})^3=0.95$. To solve for $\sigma$, first take the cube root of both sides, then do some more algebraic manipulation.

Comment: Okay I did so and got an answer for σ, however what theorem is this because I cannot find it anywhere in my notes.

Comment: What theorem is what? An exponential $X$ with mean $\sigma$ has density function $\frac{1}{\sigma}e^{-x/\sigma}$, and then $\Pr(X\le a)$ is the integral from $0$ to $a$ of the density function. This integral turns out to be $1-e^{-a/\sigma}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$p(0\le X\le x)=1-e^{-\lambda X}$$
where $\lambda$ is $1/\text{mean}$. When $x=1$, the mean is $a$, and so  the equation becomes $1-e^{-1/a}$.